# ADO components are present in the Delphi 2009 Professional Version? 

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

ADO components are present in the Delphi 2009 Professional Version? Currently I'm using delphi 5 professional version which does not include the ADO components.
thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Ado components are present in All the versions of delphi 2009.

Check the [feature matrix of delphi 2009](http://www.seidl-software.com/produkte/borland_pdf/Delphi2009FeatureMatrix.pdf)  and look for

> dbGO™ for ADO connectivity for Win32 (MDAC 2.8)

Comment: and in D2007 prof as well if you don't want to do the Unicode upgrade, but you would miss out on a lot of new functionality.